# cpp Why boost::thread inside for loop not iterating through all values and same values are being pushed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, bash, boost

i am trying to use `boost::thread` to run bash script on `command line` in parallel.

bash script writes args values to the log file.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    std::string nIndexLine = nIndex[i].line;
    boost::thread z(CommandLineRun, nIndexLine);
}


void CommandLineRun(const std::string& Command)
{
    int systemRet = system(Command.c_str());

    if(systemRet == -1){
        // The system method failed
    }
}
```

above code works, but i see `same entries multiple times`, in the `log file`. .e.g. if `nIndex` has 500 `values` then value of `nIndex[0]` gets written 500 times in `log file`.

so imho for loop is not iterating through all entries., but if i remove `boost::thread`, then for loop is working as expected.

What am i doing wrong ?

i dont want any output from command line, i just want it to run the command on command line. and dont bother with it again.

---

update : turns out

`boost::raplce_all` causing the issue. it was just before `boost::thread`

Comment: And you've made sure that the content of `nIndex[i].line` is different for every `i`?

Comment: How long does nIndexLine exist?

Comment: @OutOfBound -- check the documentation for the `boost::thread`. Its destructor detaches the thread, so whatever benefit you might get from detaching is already there.

Comment: @Murphy yes, its different everytime.

Comment: @manni66 its random count sometimes 1/2/4/500+

Comment: Minimal complete example please, or question will be voted to close.

Comment: The argument to commandLineRun should not be a reference, but a value.  And the value passed to the thread constructor should not be a copy of the array contents, but should be a direct reference into the array.  i.e: `boost::thread z(CommandLineRun, nIndex[i].line);`

Answer (score 1):

Your `CommandLineRun()` function receives a reference to a string that may have changed, or even disappeared when the function is actually called.

You should try this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
    boost::thread z(CommandLineRun, nIndex[i].line); // refer to the original string.
    z.detach();                 // making this explicit makes your intent clear
}


void CommandLineRun(std::string Command)  // getting a copy of the string
{
    int systemRet = system(Command.c_str());

    if(systemRet == -1){
        // The system method failed
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor), arguments are copied regardless of the signature of `CommandLineRun`.

Comment: Then again, the OP does get garbage in.

Comment: @sbabbi The boost documentation says nothing about removing the ref signature out of the arguments.  AFAIK, a const ref is copied as a const ref.

Comment: It is passed as per `boost::bind(func, args)`, which always performs a copy of the arguments.